# More efficient way to get one row from joined table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following two (simplified) tables and columns:

Table 1: Course
Columns: CourseID

Table 2: CourseVersion
Columns: CourseVersionID, CourseID, Active, UpdateDate, Field1, Field2... etc

I want to get the single latest active CourseVersion row for each Course row (or no row if there is no active CourseVersion row). Note that the latest UpdateDate may not be the latest CourseVersionID.

Presently I have a query like this:

```
SELECT cv.* FROM Course AS c
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 CourseVersion.* FROM CourseVersion
    WHERE CourseVersion.CourseID = c.CourseID AND CourseVersion.Active = 1
    ORDER BY CourseVersion.UpdateDate DESC) AS cv
```

This works well enough but is slow.

Any general suggestions for how to make this more efficient?

NB. Using SQL Server 2012

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Later versions have windowing functions which can be used. What's the query plan look like? If you press CTRL-L it will show the query plan and suggest indexes.

Comment: SQL Server 2012. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
with cte as(
    select
        *,
        rn = row_number() over(partition by CourseID order by UpdateDate desc)
    from CourseVersion
    where
        Active = 1
)
select
    cv.* --exclude rn
from course c
inner join cte cv
    on cv.CourseID = c.CourseID
where
    cv.rn = 1
```

Comment: I tried this and it works but execution time is around 1100ms for my test data as opposed to around 700ms for my original query using the CROSS APPLY.

Comment: If you don't need anything from the course table, just select directly from the cte and remove the join. This might help speed up the query.

Comment: Still around the same time with just the cte and no join.

Comment: It's possible you need better indexes. BTW this is the answer since you need entire row.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what information you need about the latest version of each course, you could simply use the following:

```
SELECT cvs.CourseID, MAX(cvs.UpdateDate)
FROM CourseVersion AS cvs
WHERE cvs.Active=1
GROUP BY cvs.CourseID
```

Comment: If this is really common, you should make a view that wraps this and treat it as a table.

Comment: I need all the columns from the CourseVersion table. Will this still work for this case?

Comment: Will the max courseversionid and max UpdateDate always be found on the same row? If so, just add MAX(CourseVersionID) to the above query. If not please define that in the question as a requirement.

Comment: No, they might not be both the max. Question updated.